# How to get index from value in 2D Numpy array

Tags: numpy

I have two arrays:

```
values_arr = [[100,1], [20,5], [40,50]...[50,30]]
images_arr = [img1, img2, img3,...imgn]
```

Both the arrays are numpy arrays.

The values_arr and images_arr are in the same order.
i.e

```
[100, 1] corresponds to img1
```

How do I get the image given the value of index?

```
index = [20,5]
```

In this case, I should get img2 given the value of index = [20,5].

Comment: You can use boolean indexing: `images_arr[(values_arr == [20,5]).all(axis=1)]`

Comment: Encode your keys into a single integer for faster lookup. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a dict as

```
values_arr_tup = [tuple(i) for i in values_arr]
dict_ = {key:value for key,value in zip(values_arr_tup ,images_arr)}
```

then perform `dict_[tuple(index)]` to get the image

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: That is because of list cannot be key in python, so I made some changes to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where` to extract the index of the item :

```
images_arr[np.where(values_arr == [20,5])[0][0]]
```